# On page reload display diffrent SWF file

Tags: html, flash

I have a html page "first" playing 1.swf and on the next page 
"reload" it plays 2.swf. How do I do that?

Code i now use for the first one:

```
<center><object  width="500" height="500" data="1.swf"></object></center>
```

Comment: It would help if you had code to work with so we know what you are doing currently.

Answer (score 2):

One really simple solution would be to create a cookie incrementer:

```
var number = parseInt(getCookie("number"));

if (number == "") {
    document.cookie="number=1";
} else {
    document.cookie="number=" + (number + 1);
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Now, every time the page reloads, `number` gets incremented by 1.

You can now remove the previous swf and create a new swf with the new source.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lexingtonpenguins/a91ob3d6/)**